# MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.OnCompletion does not work after audio's finishing

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I'm coding a music player that plays file after another but when the first file ended, it stopped. I tried some TAG and found out the problem is "OnCompletion" does not run eventhough the audio finished. I read some questions/answers that seem similar to my case but none of them work. I'm Java newbie, so I'm so confused. Anyone pls point my mistakes. Here my code:

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{
private static MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
private ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
private int songPos;
private boolean shuffle=false;
private Random rand;
public static final String TAG ="MyMessage";
public MusicService() {
}

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    songPos = 0;
    rand = new Random();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    Log.i(TAG,"create");
}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.i(TAG, "complete");
    mp.reset();
    if (shuffle) {
        int checkSong = songPos;
        while (checkSong == songPos)
            songPos = rand.nextInt(songs.size());
        playSong();
    } else {
        if (songPos == (songs.size() - 1))
            songPos = 0;
        else songPos++;
        playSong();
    }
}





public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

public void setList (ArrayList<Song> theSongs){
    songs=theSongs;
}

public class MusicBinder extends Binder{
    MusicService getService(){
        return  MusicService.this;
    }
}

private final IBinder musicBind=new MusicBinder();

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return musicBind;
}

public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
    return false;
}

public void setSong (int songIndex){
    songPos=songIndex;
}

public void clickPlay (){
    Log.i(TAG,"clickplay");
    if(shuffle){
        songPos=rand.nextInt(songs.size());
        clickLV();
    }
    else
        clickLV();

}

public void playSong(){
    Song playSong = songs.get(songPos);
    long currentSong = playSong.getID();
    Uri trackUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,currentSong);
    player= MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),trackUri);
    player.start();
}
public void clickLV(){
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    playSong();
}
public void clickNext(){
    player.stop();
    if(shuffle){
        int checkSong = songPos;
        while (checkSong==songPos)
            songPos=rand.nextInt(songs.size());
        playSong();
    }
    else{
        if(songPos==(songs.size()-1))
            songPos=0;
        else songPos++;
        playSong();
    }
}
public void clickPre(){
    player.stop();
    if(shuffle){
        int checkSong = songPos;
        while (checkSong==songPos)
            songPos=rand.nextInt(songs.size());
        playSong();
    }
    else{
        if(songPos==0)
            songPos=(songs.size()-1);
        else songPos--;
        playSong();
    }
}
public void clickBF(){
    player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition()-5000);
}
public void clickFF(){
    player.seekTo(player.getCurrentPosition()+5000);
}

public void setShuffle(){
    if(shuffle) shuffle=false;
    else shuffle=true;
```

And the Logcat:

```
   ========================================
   03-13 07:14:10.722 273-10470/? D/FFMPEG: android source close
   03-13 07:14:10.722 273-10470/? D/FFmpegExtractor: SniffFFMPEG failed to sniff this source
   03-13 07:14:10.725 10298-10298/sample.musicplayersample3 E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
   03-13 07:14:10.726 273-273/? D/NuPlayerDriver: start(0xef6e3c40)
   03-13 07:14:10.727 273-10469/? I/GenericSource: start
   03-13 07:14:10.737 10298-10298/sample.musicplayersample3 E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
   03-13 07:14:10.758 273-10476/? D/AudioSink: bufferCount (8) is too small and increased to 12
   03-13 07:14:12.609 273-644/? D/NuPlayerDriver: seekTo(0xef6e3c40) 242512 ms
   03-13 07:14:12.627 273-10469/? I/NuPlayer: audio discontinuity (formatChange=0, time=1)
   03-13 07:14:25.669 273-10470/? E/MP3Extractor: Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
   03-13 07:14:27.245 273-10470/? E/MP3Extractor: Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
   03-13 07:14:28.240 273-616/? I/AudioFlinger: BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4097) from active list on thread 0xf380100
```

Only the first file get those lines "Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream."